# Does the limit of $\sin (\pi/x)$ converge or diverge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Does the limit converge or diverge? Justify your answer. $$\lim_{x\to0} [\sin(\pi/x)] $$

I know for sure that the limit **diverges**. I know I can use sub-sequences because it is a sine function, and I can show that it has two subsequential limits, thus the limit diverges. I just can't figure out what subsequences to use and how to show it.

Comment: First, what about $x_n = 1/n$? Then $\sin(\pi/x_n) = \sin(n\pi) = 0$ for all $n$. Then, try $x_n = 2/(4n-3)$, which gives $\sin(\pi/x_n) = \sin((4n-3)\pi/2) = 1$ for all $n$.

Comment: You can use an alternating sequence

Comment: It appears that by "diverge" you mean "not converge" and then in this sense the function does diverge. Some books use "diverge" to mean "diverge to $\pm\infty" $ and there is another term "oscillate" to describe the behavior of the function in this question. I prefer to say $\sin(\pi/x) $ oscillates finitely as $x\to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$$\sin(n\pi)=0=\sin(\frac{\pi}{\frac{1}{n}})$$

$$\sin(\frac\pi 2+2n\pi)=1=\sin(\frac{\pi}{...})$$

Answer (score 0):

Since the sine is a periodic function, a good approach is trying sequences $y_n$ and $x_n$ satisfying both $f(x_n)$ and $f(y_)n$ are constants, but $x_n \neq y_n$. Can you guess such sequences?

You should try to take a look on the graph of the function.

Comment: $x_n$ and $y_n$ are constants?

Comment: I am sorry, the fuction applied at those points is constanr

Answer (score 0):

Let consider the case $x=\frac1y\to 0^+ \quad y \to \infty$ then

$$\sin (\pi/x)=\sin (y\pi )$$

and then the subsequence

$$y_n=\frac12+n \implies \sin (\pi y_n)=\cos(n\pi) \to \pm 1$$